# How to find numbers in string with no spaces

Tags: python

I'm searching for numbers in a string and for case where there is space after the numbers then I'm getting correct output but for cases where there is no space after the number, How to handle that

```
pds = [int(s) for s in message.split() if s.isdigit()]
print(pds)
```

for `i/p` -

Is this the right number 560 or 670 ?

In this case i get 2 outputs

for `i/p` -

Is this the right number 560 or 670?

In this case I get 1 output i.e 560

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = 'Is this the right number 560 or 670?'
nums = [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]

print(nums)
# [560, 670]
```